What is LG type Thread?
A tube fitting manufacturer is saying: St.St. 316 Male Connector, Let-Lok® Tube Fitting 3/8" x Male ISO Parallel Thread 1/2" (LG Type). What is LG type stand for? What is LG type tread?

See what looks like a duplicate question https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35998/what-does-lg-mean-when-defining-form-of-screws but it doesn't make sense in this case. Can you post a link to the specification you've quoted?

probably badly formatted webpage
